# Incrementing last digit number for number of mongodb in java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a string ABC2022050400000000 and last digits should be incremented .Trying with the  below logic and the string is incrementing line below .Something is wrong with  the syntax .Could anyone help me please
ABC2022050400000000
ABC2022050400000001

It should be like this:
ABC2022050400000001
ABC2022050400000002
to
ABC2022050400002110

```
for(int i=0;i<paddedID.length();i++) {
                String newTitleSearch;
                int len = paddedID.length();
                String allButLast = paddedID.substring(0, len - 1);
                System.out.println(allButLast);
                int val=1;
                newTitleSearch = allButLast + new Character((char) (paddedID.charAt(len - 1) +val++));
                System.out.println(newTitleSearch);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the input between letters and digit using either substring method if the prefix `ABC` has a fixed length or using regex if it is dinamic. Then parse the digit part to long and increment it and concatenate back:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input   = "ABC2022050400000000";
    String[] split = input.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
    String prefix  = split[0];
    long initial   = Long.parseLong(split[1]);

    for (long i = initial; i < initial + 50; i++){
        System.out.println(prefix+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response . It worked well